# Filter field value of a document while inserting into elastic search index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a simple requirement where in i need to create a template which will filter the value of a field before inserting it into Elastic search index.

**Elastic search version : 7.10.2**

Example :  I have created a template like below.

```
PUT /index_test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
    "id": {
        "type": "keyword"
       
      },
    "id_type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but, I want to put a filter on the value of id_type as "social", only then this filed should be inserted into the document otherwise it should be only id or other fields(in future) will be inserted.

I tried to explore **fieldData** option but it does not access the value rather it takes true or false. that not expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using an [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) that will filter the value before indexing the document.

First, create a pipeline that will remove the `id_type` field if it doesn't satisfy a given condition:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/type-filter
{
  "description": "Filter the id_type field",
  "processors": [
    {
      "remove": {
        "if": "ctx.id_type != 'social'",
        "field": "id_type"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, when indexing your documents, you can reference this ingest pipeline so that all documents will have to go through it before being indexed.

```
PUT index_test/_doc/1?pipeline=type-filter
{
   "id": "123",
   "id_type": "social"       <--- this field will be indexed
}

PUT index_test/_doc/1?pipeline=type-filter
{
   "id": "456",
   "id_type": "anything"     <--- this field won't be indexed
}
```

Comment: could see its working, thanks. but wanted to understand the performance of this approach. as this is a streaming application and in every second there are almost 50k records are processed. will this pipeline cost it anyway ?

Comment: Since this is a streaming application, if you can do this check/processing further up the stream, it's even better. If not, I think this additional pipeline is negligible as it's not doing any heavy processing.

Comment: Alright thanks. will be putting it for performance runs and update here for future reference. thanks for the quick reverts :).

Comment: could you please help me with the equivalent java reference where i am trying to push bulk documents and that is being pipelined.

Comment: Sure, but since this question is closed and this concerns another issue, please feel free to ask a new question with the new requirement so we don't cram too much into this one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70753459/applying-pipeline-to-resthighlevelclient-bulk-api-in-elastic-search-using-java --> here is a question. please help me with that too