# Applying pipeline to RestHighLevelClient bulk API in Elastic search using java

Tags: elasticsearch

[Filter field value of a document while inserting into elastic search index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70738304/filter-field-value-of-a-document-while-inserting-into-elastic-search-index/70738374?noredirect=1#comment125075359_70738374)

Continuing to the above question, I would need to actually address the bulk request call with a pipeline to it. Below is the method called for every add or delete document request.
I would need to add a pipeline suggested in the previous question to every bulk request being processed by below method.

```
 private void pushToElasticSearch(BulkRequest bulkRequest) {
      
        if (bulkRequest.estimatedSizeInBytes() > 0) {
            try {
                LOGGER.info("performing es bulk operation");
                BulkResponse bulkResponse = client.bulk(bulkRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
             //loggers
            }
        }
    }
```

**what I did ?**
I found that there is a method in bulkrequest.pipeline("myPipelineName") but not sure on this.

**UPDATE with more code:** with the below code it is not filtering the "id_type".

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = getESConnection();
        BulkRequest bulkRequest = new BulkRequest();
        JSONObject inputJson = new JSONObject();
        inputJson.put("key1","value1");
        inputJson.put("key2","value2");
        inputJson.put("id_type","test");

        bulkRequest.add(indexOrUpdateDocument("index_test","doc1", inputJson.toString()));
        bulkRequest.pipeline("type-filter");
        System.out.println( "isPipelineExists: "+isExistingPipeline("type-filter",restHighLevelClient));
        pushToElasticSearch(bulkRequest,restHighLevelClient);
        GetResponse getStagingResp= getDocument("index_test","doc1",restHighLevelClient);
        System.out.println(getStagingResp.getSourceAsMap().toString());
    }

   private static UpdateRequest indexOrUpdateDocument(String index, String documentId, String payload) {
        UpdateRequest updateRequest = null;
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(index) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(documentId) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(payload)) {
                updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(index, documentId).docAsUpsert(true).doc(payload,
                    XContentType.JSON);
        }
        return updateRequest;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily [reference a pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-bulk.html) when sending a bulk request by simply calling:

```
bulkRequest.pipeline("pipelineId");
```

Comment: this doesn't seems to be working. I have tried multiple ways. i have update my question with the more code which will be calling pushToElasticSearch method. please have a look.

Comment: One thing is that pipelines **cannot be used** when updating documents (i.e. `UpdateRequest`) with `doc_as_upsert = true`, only when indexing them. See the [note](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#doc_as_upsert) at the bottom of this page.

Comment: then what is the appropriate way of doing this then ? if pipelines cannot be used here then should i need to manually process it at java end ? what do you suggest?